# SQL to return a merged set of results

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT `table1`.`value`, `table2`.* 
FROM `table2` 
INNER JOIN `table1` ON `table2`.`product_id` = `table1`.`entity_id`
WHERE `table2`.`created_at` > '2012-04-23' and 
(`table1`.`value` = 264 OR `table1`.`value` = 260)
order by order_id
```

Which returns a result set like this (This is only a part of the returned results):

```
value  order_id   ...
260    1234
260    1235
260    1236
264    1236
260    1237
260    1238
260    1239
264    1239
264    1240
260    1241
```

What I want is a query that will take these results and only return orders where the order_id contains both value 260 and 264. Based on this example, the end result I am looking for is

```
260   1236
264   1236
260   1239
264   1239
```

My thought is this can be done with a subset but I am not exactly sure on the details to accomplish it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this.  Can you create an SQLfiddle with some test data?

Comment: do you need both `value` and `order_id` or just a list of `order_id`s that have both 260 and 264 value? the former case is already answered, the latter one is a simple self-join (that will be much more faster)

Comment: @deathApril good point about the self-join, with the caveat that it will be harder to extend when the list grows to 3 `order_id`s ... then 4, 5 ....

Comment: Just the list of order_id s that have both 260 and 264 would be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [relational division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29):

```
select r.order_id from (
  select 
    dividend.*  
  from your_table_or_query as dividend  -- assumes no duplicates in `dividend`; use `distinct` if there are any
  inner join divisor
  on dividend.value = divisor.value
) as r
group by r.order_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from divisor);
```

result:

```
+----------+
| order_id |
+----------+
|     1236 |
|     1239 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

where your query is `your_table_or_query` and

```
select 260 as value from dual union select 264 as value from dual
```

is `divisor`.

This will return the order ids 1236 and 1239; they can then be `join`ed to original query to get all the rows with those order ids if that's what you want.

---

Full query along with insert statements:

```
create table divisor (value int);
insert into divisor values (260), (264);

create table your_table_or_query (value int, order_id int);
insert into your_table_or_query values (260, 1234), (260, 1235), (260, 1236), (264, 1236), (260, 1237), (260, 1238), (260, 1239), (264, 1239), (264, 1240), (260, 1241);


select y.* from (
  select r.order_id from (
    select
      dividend.*
    from your_table_or_query as dividend
    inner join divisor
      on dividend.value = divisor.value
  ) as r 
  group by r.order_id
  having count(*) = (select count(*) from divisor)
) as quotient
inner join your_table_or_query y
  on quotient.order_id = y.order_id;
```

Result:

```
+-------+----------+
| value | order_id |
+-------+----------+
|   260 |     1236 |
|   264 |     1236 |
|   260 |     1239 |
|   264 |     1239 |
+-------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1 great general-purpose solution,, but in this particular case i think it is a bit too costly using `having` instead of a simple join..

Comment: How costly it is will depend mainly on the context:  size of input, size of output etc.

Comment: This took me a while to wrap my head around what 'divisor' should be but eventually I got there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT table1.value, table2.* 
FROM table2 
INNER JOIN table1 
ON table2.product_id = table1.entity_id
WHERE table2.created_at > '2012-04-23' AND
(table1.value = 264 OR table1.value = 260)
AND table2.order_id IN (
    SELECT table2.order_id  
    FROM table2 
    INNER JOIN table1 
    ON table2.product_id = table1.entity_id
    WHERE table2.created_at > '2012-04-23' AND
    (table1.value = 264 OR table1.value = 260)
    GROUP BY table2.order_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

(sorry for omitting apostrophes, I am not aware what are mysql requirements in this field; this syntax is ms-sql compliant)

Comment: I started with this but the time to execute on the server was too much for it to bear and I had to stop the process. It may be a viable solution but not one for 4,600+ records.

Answer (score 1):

this will return a list of orders that have both values 260 and 264 - if someone needs just this result instead of duplicated results for each of the value:

```
SELECT `table2`.* 
FROM `table2` 
INNER JOIN `table1` as `table1_264`
  ON `table2`.`product_id` = `table1_264`.`entity_id`
  AND `table1_264`.`value` = 264
INNER JOIN `table1` as `table1_260`
  ON `table2`.`product_id` = `table1_260`.`entity_id`
  AND `table1_260`.`value` = 260
WHERE `table2`.`created_at` > '2012-04-23'
order by order_id
```

---

or if someone wanted faster solution without costly `having` clauses (+ of course you can store the query or use a CTE instead of just repeating it)

```
SELECT 264 as `value`, `table2`.* 
 FROM `table2` 
 INNER JOIN `table1` as `table1_264` ON `table2`.`product_id` = `table1_264`.`entity_id` AND `table1_264`.`value` = 264
 INNER JOIN `table1` as `table1_260` ON `table2`.`product_id` = `table1_260`.`entity_id` AND `table1_260`.`value` = 260
 WHERE `table2`.`created_at` > '2012-04-23'
UNION ALL
SELECT 260, `table2`.* 
 FROM `table2` 
 INNER JOIN `table1` as `table1_264` ON `table2`.`product_id` = `table1_264`.`entity_id` AND `table1_264`.`value` = 264
 INNER JOIN `table1` as `table1_260` ON `table2`.`product_id` = `table1_260`.`entity_id` AND `table1_260`.`value` = 260
 WHERE `table2`.`created_at` > '2012-04-23'
order by order_id
```

Comment: For some reason when I ran this I would get zero results. Removing one of the inner joins would get me the correct number of sub items and the logic is sound so I upvoted it as a possible solution for someone else. In all aspects it should work but I moved on to a different solution as I had options.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `table1`.`value`, `table2`.* 
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`entity_id` = `table2`.`product_id`
WHERE
(`table1`.`value` = 264 OR `table1`.`value` = 260)
AND `table2`.`created_at` > '2012-04-23' 
ORDER BY `table2`.order_id
```

Left join so it only matches the  table1.value results with matches and leave the info from the other table out

Comment: I believe the `LEFT JOIN` will do just the opposite.

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood the question then

Comment: Your answer seems to be okay, what is needed is what you added to `WHERE`. Your `LEFT JOIN` will actually behave like an `INNER JOIN` because `WHERE` contains a condition on `table2`.

Comment: are you sure? the condition for the second table to is `AND` so if it doesn't meet the previous condition it will be filtered out no?

Comment: the difference between inner and outer joins is how `null` values will be handled. `>` (greater than inequality operator) will be falsy if either argument is null.  => this is the same as an inner join